# Is there a way to check if a function (name and signature) has been define within a namespace

Tags: c++11

I want to call a namespace defined function within a template method, and want to use std::enable_if to have that method generated only if the target namespace defined function exists. Is it possible?

I should add that the calling method takes a parameter that has its type defined within a namespace. And that is the namespace I want to check.

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    ...
    void SomeFunc(...);

    class SomeType { ... };
}

template <class T>
void MyClass::MyMethod(const SomeNamespace::SomeType& obj)
{
   ...
   SomeNamespace::SomeFunc(...);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Not unless `SomeFunc` has an argument that is related to `SomeType` in some way.

Comment: Can you clarify. When you say to @toth that the target namespace is *arbitrary*, do you mean you *don't even know it's name*, or do you just mean that it is a namespace you are *given*?

Comment: @Mike Kinghan: In the post above, the code underneath "I should add that ..." has the SomeNamespace and that is the namespace I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do it with `std::enable_if`, but one way to achieve it is the following (this is assuming that `func` takes a single argument, should be easy to generalize to multiple arguments):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace NS {
   void func(int x)
   {
      std::cout << "func called with arg " << x << std::endl;
   }


   void call_func(...)
   {
      std::cout << "func does not exist" << std::endl;
   }

   template<typename T>
   auto call_func(T t) -> decltype( func(t), void())
   {
      std::cout << "func exists, calling it" << std::endl;
      func(t);
   }
} 

int main()
{
    call_func(2);
    return 0;
}
```

This will produce the output

```
func exists, calling it
func called with arg 2
```

But if you comment out the definition of `func`, you get:

```
func does not exist
```

It is a bit clunky, in that `call_func` overloads need to be defined inside the same namespace as `func`, otherwise it does not work. To make it more reusable, you could wrap the `call_func` definitions inside some macro with `NS` and `func` args.

Comment: Thanks toth for your suggestion. But I am after a solution that can take care of arbitrary namespace. And unfortunately, using macro is not an option in my environment.

Comment: @simon, I don't think it is possible then. The language does not have a way of using the name of a namespace as a parameter (template or otherwise), except for macros.